# How to setup CORS on user login

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm getting `Not injecting HSTS header` error but still have no idea after googling this message.

> o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@30cc5ff

What I have done is below.

> API request http://localhost:8083/api/v1/users/login

## Web config

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();



        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL)
                .permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable().addFilterBefore(corsFilter, AuthorizationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated();


    protected AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/v1/users/login");
        return filter;
    }
```

## CorsFilter

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        // without this header jquery.ajax calls returns 401 even after successful login and SSESSIONID being succesfully stored.
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Version");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type");

        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        if (!request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            // do not continue with filter chain for options requests
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Comment: It is only a debug log. What does not work? What response do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSTS stands for [Http Strict Transport Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/default-security-headers-2.html#webflux-headers-hsts) and is one of the [default headers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/default-security-headers-2.html) being included when using Spring Security.

If you have your own security configuration set up and are sure you can disable the HSTS security header, use:

```java
http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable();
```